# How to verify Hash of a plainText instead of plainText itself

Tags: java, digital-signature, sha1

I'm trying to verify a SHA1 With RSA signature in Java. My code is actually this :

```
String plainText = "myString";
String signature_b64_encoded = "bOBrJmPGJ6eqDpk7sZMJZ0QujErTVz/boe44ANTLbeHd1Pm56UBH3uUCdH4sDZcDczIW5E6Q0o2dq/4lpjTAOzu3FjaLMAZ1sSTn8Ds8XxQnOnmhapbrd/6sNSr9fC57c7BlgAy7GZbCZGUQC/b/UETb8cIR0B1Dqk41RDorm+NdwDEVCTl4q9I7D70/Kau/aGpUvJ3ULgzM3/JnxHpaWmG7xAsXH9MyxVSxi/ZpJ0WuyuaAiSmiDN946O/ElIxRqnaEtFuSIDinUYz4yAWtoLdssDO5SqMFb8EskUdfExs1IcGtYRaIbz3ASTFdVQoou7HI4pxVn1Sh4Y4mrxa7Ag==";
Signature instance = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
PublicKey pkey = cert.getPublicKey(); // gets my Public Key
instance.initVerify(pkey);
instance.update(plainText.getBytes());
Boolean blnResult = instance.verify(Base64.decode(strSignature.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

The problem is that the signature verified is false only in some cases and in other cases it is true. I don't manage to understand the cause of the randomness of this result.

- The string i'm trying to verify is signed in .NET environment
- The verification of the signature done in .NET is made **on the hash of the plainText and not on the plainText**.

**Question 1**

Is there a means to verify the hash of the plainText instead of plainText itself in Java (as it is possible in .NET) ? This would allow to be sure to have the same input at the beginning of the verification process.

**Question 2**

Is there another way to verify a SHA1 with RSA signature in Java ?

Comment: What's the difference between cases where you get different results?

Comment: The difference in my code is only due to different orderData value content, but the OrderData is base64 encoded. 90% of the time, my code works.